# Android SurfaceHolder Как сохранить фото в хорошем качестве

Tags: android, камера

Помогите плиз, в превью показываю изображение с камеры, оно в хорошем качестве, все ок.
Делаю фото:   paramCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);

и получаю callback:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
    Log.i("TEST_CAMMM", "onPictureTaken()");
    btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnUnsave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnRestartCam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    this.bytes = bytes.clone();
}
```

по нажатию на кнопку сохраняю изображение:

```
case R.id.btnSave:
            btnSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnUnsave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnRestartCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            SavePhotoTask savePhotoTask = new SavePhotoTask();
            savePhotoTask.doInBackground(bytes);
            camera.startPreview();
            break;
```

SavePhotoTask:

```
class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
        savePhoto(jpeg);
        //makeScreenshotOfView(llScreen);
        return (null);
    }

    private void savePhoto(byte[]... jpeg) {
        OutputStream fos = null;
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setToNow();
        try {
            String fileName = Integer.toString(time.year) + Integer.toString(time.month)
                    + Integer.toString(time.monthDay) + Integer.toString(time.hour)
                    + Integer.toString(time.minute) + Integer.toString(time.second) + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(jpeg[0]);
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Файл: " + fileName + " сохранен в корневой директории телефона", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка сохранения файла", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

В итоге сохраняется фото низкого качества, к тому же и перевернутое(ну эт ладно)

И я посмотрел логи, размер массива байт = 3110400
размер фото 20,2 кб
Куда деваются остальные байты? и как пофиксить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем сам разобрался, большой размер был потому что это измерение превью, а не самой фотки.
А чтобы сделать фотку в хорошем качестве нужно добавить параметр:

```
  Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size sizePicture = supportedSizes.get(0);
        parameters.setPictureSize(sizePicture.width, sizePicture.height);
```

С листа можно получить возможные разрешения и выбрать лучший, я так понял,что они идут в порядке убывания,по этому и поставил нулевой индекс.